# Differing behaviour of GeneratingFunction with different numbers of parameters

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

When given a single variable sequence, `GeneratingFunction` is automatically expressed in the most "direct form", for example,

```
GeneratingFunction[(i + 1) v[i - 1], i, x]
```

returns something like

```
2 x GeneratingFunction[v[i], i, x] + v[-1] + x^2 D[GeneratingFunction[v[i], i, x],x]
```

But, if I add an extra variable that does not otherwise affect the result

```
GeneratingFunction[(i + 1) v[i - 1, j], {i, j}, {x, y}]
```

then the function is not evaluated in the same way, although, it would seem that it would be correct to return

```
2 x GeneratingFunction[(i + 1) v[i - 1, j], {i, j}, {x, y}] + v[-1,j]
 + x^2 D[GeneratingFunction[(i + 1) v[i - 1, j], {i, j}, {x, y}],x]
```

what is happening here, how can I make it behave in a way that would fit this intuition?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include `j` or `y` in `GeneratingFunction[]`, then you get something like what you want:

```
GeneratingFunction[(i + 1) v[i - 1, j], i, x]
   2 x GeneratingFunction[v[i, j], i, x] + v[-1, j] +
   x^2 Derivative[0, 0, 1][GeneratingFunction][v[i, j], i, x]
```